# Stuck in creating a simple HW Project

Tags: c#

I am completely new to programming, and my professor for my intro cs class gave us a project to create a menu using c# while being able to pick 2 games to play. I decided to go for a math game however I am stuck with a problem that part of my code does not read and I wonder why?

```
private static void FindTheAnswer()
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Find the Answer Math Game");
    Console.WriteLine("1. 12x = 3");
    Console.WriteLine("Choose the Answer: ");
    Console.WriteLine("1) 1/4 ");
    Console.WriteLine("2) 4 ");
    Console.WriteLine("3) 12x-3 ");
    Console.WriteLine("1) 3-12x");
    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
        
    if (userValue =="1/4")
    // ...
}
```

I expect the program to ask me these lines :

> "Find the Answer Math Game"
>
> "1. 12x = 3"
>
> "Choose the Answer: "

However, it only reads up to "1. 12x = 3" and whatever answer I enter to from the codes I inputted does not read it and it constantly repeats the menu.

Complete Code I have:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MainGameMenu
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //when you do not know how many times to itterate upfront

            bool displayMenu = true;

            while (displayMenu == true)
            {

                displayMenu = MainMenu();

            }

        }

        private static bool MainMenu()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Choose an option: ");

            Console.WriteLine("1) Option 1");

            Console.WriteLine("2) Option 2");

            Console.WriteLine("3) Exit");

            string result = Console.ReadLine();

            if (result == "1")
            {

                FindTheAnswer();

                return true;

            }

            if (result == "2")
            {

                FindTheLoot();

                return true;

            }

            if (result == "3")
            {

                return false;

            }

            else
            {

                return true;

            }

        }

        private static void FindTheAnswer()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Find the Answer Math Game");
            Console.WriteLine("1. 12x = 3");
            Console.WriteLine("Choose the Answer: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1) 1/4 ");
            Console.WriteLine("2) 4 ");
            Console.WriteLine("3) 12x-3 ");
            Console.WriteLine("1) 3-12x");
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            if (userValue == "1/4")
            {
                string message = "The Answer is Correct!";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }

            else if (userValue == "4")
            {
                string message = "Incorrect Answer";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }

            else if (userValue == "12x-3")
            {
                string message = "Incorret Answer";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }


            else if (userValue == "3-12x")
            {
                string message = "Incorrect Answer";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }

            else
            {
                string message = "Sorry, We didn't understand.";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }


            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        private static void FindTheLoot()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Select the Number that Matches");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use the debugger set a breakpoint on your if statement and see if you arrive there

Comment: I could not get the phrase  *it only reads up to* particularly. Can you share the current output as you did for the desired one? And maybe the rest of your code, too.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. People tend to avoid answering low-quality homework questions. You can follow this source to ask it properly https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: It works for me. Please post the full code. Have you tried running your code under a debugger?

Comment: The code you show looks right to me.  I suspect that your problem is later in your code.  My guess is that you do not pause after showing the result, before resetting the menu, so it only appears that the remainder of your code does not happen.  Computers are fast(!) and you may simply not be seeing the change in your console.

Comment: Try to set a breackpoint at the end of the method to check how it works, if you dont know how to use breackpoints, print some values and use Console.ReadKey() to stop the program.

Comment: Something was wrong with the code you posted.  The FindTheLoot() method was outside the class (which is not allowed).  Check my edit.  This code seems to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 Console.WriteLine("Find the Answer Math Game");
    Console.WriteLine("1. 12x = 3");
    Console.WriteLine("Choose the Answer: ");
    Console.WriteLine("1) 1/4 ");
    Console.WriteLine("2) 4 ");
    Console.WriteLine("3) 12x-3 ");
    Console.WriteLine("1) 3-12x");
    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userValue =="1/4")
        Console.WriteLine("correct");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("wrong");
```

Comment: I would suggest you explain what you have done in addition to the code in question to get this working

Comment: I checked your full code it's also worked for me but the method FindTheLoot() 
doesn't have work to do it just write some text and exit